# Correct SqlConnection declaration

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqlconnection

The problem is that I have used my `SqlConnection` as a public static connection, thinking this might be the problem causing form time to time an error :

> *the connection is not open or the connection was already open

So is it ok to use one statement of `SqlConnection` in a static class?

So that I could *Declare* it only once, I know I could use `connectionString` in `web.config`

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString ...
```

but I like it to stay unrelated to `web.config` settings or servers name.

- ReEdit :

as it is realy two methods within same class theres also another class in that main class 
but this is not what's important rather than using same connection for all 
executions ! so you say that even though i re edited with right code of my helprer class 
this is wrong ?

```
public static class myDBhelper
{
 public static SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection ("server=(local);Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True");

        public static int ExecSQLint(string TblintSQL)
        {
            int anIntValue=0;
            SqlCommand TblintCMD = new SqlCommand(TblintSQL, Conn);
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
                anIntValue = Convert.ToInt32(TblintCMD.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("No Can Do: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }
          return anIntValue;
        }



        public static string ExecSQLstring(string TblStrSQL)
        {
          string strValue="";
          SqlCommand TblStrCMD = new SqlCommand(TblStrSQL, Conn);
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
                strValue = TblStrCMD.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("No Can Do: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }

            return strValue;
        }


}
```

The main issue I suspect is those two options :

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=True;database=dbName")
```

in my `DBhelper` class I was using this declaration

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True");
```

could that be unstable or error prone ?

p.s.: I am executing commands via try catch

```
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("No Can Do: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }
```

Is `Using` statement more appropriate? Although it is not my problem I was thinking... if I am already trying to do it 'by the book'...

Is any method here actually **wrong** among those ?

Comment: why are you having the command objects on a inner class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keeping Connection as static is not a *common way* to use connection to database. It could lead to exception as you mentioned when application is working on web or multi-thread environment.

Image that thread 1 executing command 1 is the same connection with thread 2 executing command 2. Your ex: TblintCMD and TblStrCMD. When thread 1 finishs, it closed connection, meanwhile thread 2 is still executing command on *close connection*

Your two options are not the problem.

The best way is to use `using` keyword and create connection when needed:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
}
```

`using` is similar with:

```
var connection =  new SqlConnection("connectionString");
try
{
    connection.Open();
    ....
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

So, you don't need to know when to close Connection.

Behind the scene, ADO.NET uses [connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) to manage connections for you automatically, so you should not care much how many connections open.

Comment: so you are actuatlly saying that in some unknown way it could lead to an error (i thought i am being paranoid thinking of that at all), the use of one public static connetcion is different analogue to declare once use many as with any other variable...

Comment: Explicitly define the datatype, no need for `var` in this case.

Comment: what about those two options i mentioned . sorry if my question is actually a few but i was trying to ask about two different options for the string ("") inside the SqlConnection declaration , is any of them wrong ? do you see what i am referring to in my post ?

Comment: You shouldn't reuse connections like that since they are already pooled by ADO.NET. Also, that approach is not thread-safe, as reffered. As for the connection string, check the syntax here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008.

Comment: Note that [ADO.NET creates separate connection poools per connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).

Comment: @Cuong Le . i am coding for both subclass1 % 2 the same try catch (gonna try using... soon) but they both have a separted command i re edit , tell me if u still support your saying "thread 1 executing command 1 is the same connection with thread 2 executing command 2" , re editing my post

Comment: @LoneXcoder: well, that's always true in general situation using one connection. For your code, somewhere happens, you need to take careful look

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var conn=new. SqlConnection( "server=(local);Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammer , so if you both did not continue the code example of `using` then i might guess it's(Conn.Close())  "been taken cared of" - by the ADO.NET ? can you please continue your sample? any of you choise of a proper one will do

Comment: conn.Close is taken care by the dispose of using... as using completes it work.. it disposes the object it has initialized...

Comment: @TheinidianPro thanks for the clearing on the issue: of disposing with `using` statement , ...what did you mean in second comment "a non static member" , who is ?

Comment: It seems you have edited your question... thats great... consider upvoting and accepting if something really helped you...

Answer (score -1):

```
public SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
{
    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection();
    sql.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolContext"].ToString();
    return sql;
}
```